# word search: voluntary pause between desire and action

Tags: translation, words, expressions

Some years ago, I read that Japanese has a word (or idiomatic expression) that means roughly:

```
The action of voluntary interposing a pause between the
moment you desire something and the moment you start 
to do something to acquire it.
```

I was never able to find it again. Does it really exist? If yes, what is it? Is it some jargon word (e.g. religion, philosophy)?

---

As @Sawa suggested, I'll try to better define my request. Imagine this sequence:

1. I see a beautiful thing in a shop window.
2. I desire it.
3. I decide to sit down and wait.
4. After  some minute, I get up and, in case, I go inside the shop to buy the thing.

I am searching for a word that describe the 3rd step of this sequence.

Comment: It is too abstract, and is difficult to even think of what area to consider. Do you have more solid explanations or examples of what you are mentioning?

Comment: @Sawa, You are right. The expression `the moment in which P` is strange and redundant. I removed it.

Comment: I cannot come up with any words matching your description.  間 (as in Dave M G’s answer) means “pause” without any connotation to desire or acquisition as far as I know, so I doubt that that is the word you are looking for.

Comment: It seems that no-one knows a word that fits my description. :-/ Do I have to think that my memory is defective and that @Dave-M-G word is the best approximation I can find? My last chance is a "bounty".

Comment: Did the text you read say *why* you would want to wait before taking action? For example, for being polite, or just because you're unsure?

Comment: Sorry, @ento. I do not remember it clearly. Perhaps it was related to the idea of "increasing the pleasure of achieving some result by waiting" or "to avoid a rush decision".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this case, I would suggest the idea of 「立ち止まる」（*tachidomaru - coming to a stand still.*)

I've seen this used by people when they are describing someone who is stopping to think about something; not yet acting (other than stopping whatever action they had been doing beforehand.)  It conveys a sense of stopping everything to ponder about the next action one is to take.  *Potentially for the sake of making a life changing decision.*

[Here is an example](http://wwwsoc.nii.ac.jp/jsse3/bbs/propose/48-3-2009.pdf) of this phrase in one type of context.

Answer (score 4):

I'm taking a risk here in that I'm not 100% sure, but, we're trying to do [answers not comments](https://japanese.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/593/comments-are-not-for-answers)...

Anyway, a long time ago I used to work in animation at a Japanese company. One of my directors stressed to me the importance of `間{ま}`, which he described as the pause a character takes just before a motion. Having just a fraction of a second of pause just before doing something, made characters appear much more natural than just bursting into action.

So I think `間{ま}` might be the word you're looking for.

Note that the kanji `間` is usually read `あいだ` when on it's own, and `かん` when part of a compound (for example, `時間{じかん}`). `ま` is a rarer reading.

Comment: That sounds like what he's describing :) Kudos for answering in an answer

Comment: Yes, it is very similar to what I am searching for. It lacks of the concept of `voluntary interposing` but probably it is the right answer. I'll wait a couple of days to select the *accepted answer*, just in case ...

Comment: 間 is an interesting choice.  Also, have you considered 立ち止まる？ (see answer below...)

Comment: I think it's 間をおいて here. It means a pause, but I don't think it's quite appropriate here because it seems to me to mean 'make a pause for effect' as much as anything else.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe one of these?

> [一]{ひと}呼吸置く
>   'take one breath'
>
> 一歩下がる
>   'take one step behind'
>
> 思いとどまる
>   'stop and think'
>
> [熟]{じゅく}[慮]{りょ}する
>   'think intensively'

Or maybe you meant these proverbs?

> 石の上にも三年
>   'Stay three years on a rock (until it becomes warm enough to be comfortable).'
>
> 石橋を叩いて渡る
>   'Hit a bridge made of rock before crossing it (to make sure it does not collapse).'
>
> 桃栗三年柿八年
>   'It takes as much as three years for a plum tree or a chestnut tree to blossom, and eight years for a persimmon tree.'

Answer (score 1):

Couldn't this just be

> 躊躇{ちゅうちょ}する、躊躇{ためら}う  to hesitate

? Or would that be too simple? I think it matches the description pretty well... or was this supposed to be some concept very specific to Japan(ese)?

Comment: Mumble, I do not think it was something like "to hesitate". Why would the author of the book have used a Japanese word to describe the concept instead of using a simple native word? It should be a word that does not have a direct equivalent in English.